# Accounts not visible on Spinnaker deck

Tags: nginx-config, spinnaker, spinnaker-halyard

I have setup a local (debian) installation of spinnaker and everything looks fine. I had also setup the `authentication` as `ldap` and able to sign in as well. 
For `authorization`, I am using the `FILE` and have already enabled.

However, When I am trying to select an account in the application which I have created, it does not list any of the accounts.

[image]

I checked the logs and I am getting the following error in the logs:

```
Request GET:http://localhost:7002/applications/samit-app/serverGroups?expand=false is missing [X-SPINNAKER-ACCOUNTS] authentication headers and will be treated as anonymous.
```

Also, the `deck` and `gate` URLs are overridden and are behind a nginx proxy.

Can someone help me here and let me know what part I am missing in this setup?

Comment: what version are you using? 
can you run `hal config provider aws`

Answer (score 0):

You must choose an Account provider to deploy to and set it as a new Account in `Halyard`.

Set up an [Account provider](https://www.spinnaker.io/setup/install/providers/)